# unable to trace out the issue in parse query

Tags: android, parse-platform

am trying to query from the parse.com's server everything is working  fine except one thing this is what am using for querying:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("TestNotes");
query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
query.fromLocalDatastore();
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

                           @Override
                           public void done(List<ParseObject> list,
                                            ParseException e) {

                               if (e == null) {

                                   if (list.size() <= 0) {


                                       getNotesFromServer();

                                       Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No results", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                   }


                                   for (ParseObject j : list) {


                                       notesIDArray.add(j.getObjectId());

                                       Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                                       String s = formatter.format(j.getCreatedAt());

                                       //problem is here 
                                       notesTimeStampArray.add(s);

                                       Log.d("TimeStamp = " + notesTimeStampArray.add(s), " TimeStamp ");
                                       Log.d("ObjectId = " + notesIDArray, " TimeStamp ");
                                   }


                               } else {

                                   e.getMessage();
                                   Log.d("" + e.getMessage(), " error");
                               }}});
  }
```

as you can see i am querying two things here the `objectIds` and their `createdAt`

and you can see that i tried to print them for seeing what i got from querying 
and the print output is:

```
D/TimeStamp = [2016-02-03 10:37:52, 2016-02-03 10:32:22, 2016-01-24 01:12:58]:  TimeStamp

D/ObjectId = [gHFxggepVj, IfY7VBZcV4, Kh0qUl4pDw, 6PONATviwa, 2t0IJ251Py, N0QSGYnv1j]:  TimeStamp
```

as you can see the `timestamp` haves only three values and my objects are more than 3 so any idea why am not getting all the values of `object's` `createdAt`

please guys help me am trying to figure this out from past 3 hours but didn't get any clue,  any clue or hint will be so helpful for me

Comment: You are calling query on your LocalDatastore by calling `query.fromLocalDatastore();`. Also call query to server and  store result in database somewhere else or in background to get the all result.

Comment: thanks for responding bro but i already have all the result in my local storage from a previous query thats why am querying here the local storage

Comment: You are printing `Log.d("TimeStamp = " + notesTimeStampArray.add, " TimeStamp ");`  is this typo mistake or something else?

Comment: fixed it , that was a typo , occurred  while posing question

Comment: `notesTimeStampArray.add(s)` returns true or false only.It add one more time timestamp in  `notesTimeStampArray`. where are you printing timestamp which you get in output.